# Looking for locking "lanyard" reel mechanism

Tags: mechanisms, mechanical

I'm working on a system that requires a small cord (~3ft long) to retract up into a reel and lock in place so it cannot be pulled away from the reel. Sort of like a seatbelt mechanism after it's been pulled too far or too hard.

I'm hoping to find something off the shelf that is small and lightweight (~100g) before building my own solution. I've found industrial spring reels like [these](https://springcompany.com/products/spring-reels), that are of the correct size and construction, but none have the locking functionality I'm looking for.

Does this mechanism sound familiar to anyone?

Comment: A lot of clothes-iron's have a self-winding / retracting reel for the cord built into them...

Comment: masterlock python will "lock" but doesnt have a retraction mechanism of its own

Comment: The word "lanyard" in the title makes me nervous - we're talking about automatic tightening and locking in the context of something that goes around a human neck.

Comment: @danielhatton does lanyard explicitly means a cord around the neck. I had seen it used for key rings most of the time. Then again I am not a native English speaker.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand - after retraction it locks, preventing unrolling again? In that case the seatbelt mechanism is the way to go. It has a spring that decides how much is 'too much', and removing it will make the mechanism seize at every weakest pull attempt.

Comment: The seatbelt lock is centrifugal so it's velocity triggered, not distance ("too far").

Comment: Dog leashes allow line to run, retract, then slide a button to lock the line in place. You could probably find a cheap one and include a ramp and stop with a bead (on the line), so once brought behind the stop will prevent the line from extending.

Comment: @NMech Short answer: yes.  Longer answer: Oxford Dictionaries' Lexico online live has "lanyard" meaning a rather wider range of things than my hard-copy 1995 edition of the Concise Oxford English Dictionary, but still yes.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the direction of extension/retraction you could use a mechanism for :

- (won't extend unless you permit it)  a extendable dog leash
- (won't retract unless you permit it) a vacuum cleaner cable retracting mechanism.

### dog leash

Basic parts of dog leash mechanism.

[image]

*Figure from [medium.com](https://medium.com/@fick0054/market-research-a9f5a60a362d)*

- [example buy from ebay](https://www.ebay.com/itm/FLEXI-Classic-Retractable-Dog-Leash-26-ft-Large-Black-Parts-or-Repair-/224231319894)

### Vaccum cleaner

You can see a patent like that in https://patents.google.com/patent/US5255768A/en.

This is an example part with a complete plug assembly you can buy from [espares.co.uk](https://www.espares.co.uk/product/es115657/vacuum-cleaner-cable-rewind-and-plug-assembly) (you can search and find something more to your specific needs).

[image]

Comment: Seems like "by default" it works in the opposite direction than OP wants, preventing unwanted retraction, instead of unwanted extension. Might be possible to modify it by reversing the spring and the direction the cable is coiled

Answer (score 1):

Dog leashes allow line to run, retract, then slide a button to lock the line in place. Dollar stores have inexpensive options.

This takes care of locking after full retraction: Include a ramp and stop with a bead (on the line), so during retraction once brought behind the stop-engagement this prevents the line from re-extending.

If you want a seat-belt function: You would need to include an inertial catch, like a centrifugal clutch, that when it spins at some pre-determined velocity, it catches the exterior and engages (in your case) the non-rotating housing.  Add dampers so that when the "catches" engage, breakage is prevented.